# python: dealing with a list of numbers taken each day of the year to get the average number

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am very new to python and I need some help because I have no idea how to deal with such a huge list from a file called "months.txt". I have a file that contains numbers taken each day of the year. I need to read the file and make it display the average numbers taken from each month. I would really appreciate any help.

here are the numbers taken each day of the year:
1102
9236
10643
2376
6815
10394
3055
3750
4181
5452
10745
9896
255
9596
1254
2669
1267
1267
1327
10207
5731
8435
640
5624
1062
3946
3796
9381
5945
10612
1970
9035
1376
1919
2868
5847
685
10578
3477
3937
5994
6971
3011
4474
4344
8068
6564
2659
4064
1161
6830
5167
5686
5352
898
4316
7699
6406
6466
2802
1239
8162
398
9908
8251
8419
6245
8484
9012
6318
853
4031
868
8776
10453
1026
1984
8127
5274
6937
1960
9655
1279
9386
6697
6326
2509
7127
7802
8798
6564
7220
10650
3847
7485
10951
3883
9456
4671
2067
6871
1573
8746
7473
4713
1215
8486
6652
4054
10304
5291
2680
9108
6446
1581
7607
2032
7630
1106
3702
986
8602
556
2209
3055
886
5813
6513
3154
1534
6271
611
4001
6522
3819
8396
2364
9660
5937
2506
9002
8586
8805
552
5802
7825
5610
8169
602
5638
2072
3536
5885
9334
6393
9318
6057
5812
5647
4654
1880
634
3084
9606
2287
3032
4030
5627
1314
8489
1601
8559
2083
5520
1829
2890
4533
3225
7405
3985
5521
1127
7109
8083
3615
1475
2896
10523
7108
797
8443
169
8755
5761
9862
9032
1659
10944
6878
1253
4690
9934
8820
41
9367
1898
3554
10650
3136
3574
9682
3950
691
8247
6677
10381
8879
8660
6431
6030
365
10357
10526
9245
5291
4651
5741
800
540
6074
68
8714
5095
4578
10841
5805
6676
2547
203
10988
604
9057
3787
2397
10984
9807
1703
6382
9793
8592
1279
8005
5297
7166
4070
4252
606
6443
10827
8140
5740
10844
8834
3695
4152
10662
8791
7791
9940
831
2999
2254
1161
808
4233
3562
3301
1530
7387
6425
9907
9752
4533
7079
3305
5286
4313
1503
6501
8201
1723
9501
9878
1844
5976
6171
10265
2607
10667
2310
836
2618
9813
5907
6849
470
8794
528
2327
2200
237
618
4898
1307
3212
1007
1322
10409
6956
8653
3462
3207
9210
1309
4431
9106
7737
1698
1117
3826
5297
5589
3199
9089
5967
3156
5919
2855
5985
1780
6267
6303
9855
3843
1816
2876
5973
2888
709
6509
4320
10342
2616
4887
10470
6084
4573
2457
10205
4627
7927
1703
5034
7042
4292

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you post a small section of code that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic interview question. Open the file. Parse it 1 number (not character) at a time. You know that white space splits the numbers, so that should be easy. Now, what is the formula for averages? Average(N) = (n1+n2+...+nn)/N). N increases each time you read a new number. Hopefully these hints help you. Good luck.